# How does slalom work on a skateboard?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have a skateboard that I like to use to get to places. I don't know how to do even the most basic tricks though. I never cared about this until I learned about slalom.

I have seen some people causing their skateboards to carry them forward on a perfectly even surface without removing their feet from the board, just by twisting their arms and hips. Now when I push with my foot I understand that Newton's Third Law of Motion is at work. But how do my peers generate motion on a board without that push, from a physics point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By varying the weight on the rear and front axles, the friction force on the wheels in the direction parallel to the axle varies.

With weight loaded on the rear axle and the board canted with the right side lower than the left side, the athlete can push himself away from the board to the right to create a leftward force on the rear axle, which transfers a leftward force to the planet via friction, and hence returns a rightward force to the athlete+board system. At the same time, the athlete torques himself anticlockwise to create an clockwise torque around the center of the rear axle. Because the friction force on the lightly loaded front wheels is small and the friction force on the heavily loaded rear wheels is large, the front wheels are free to skid while the back wheels resist skidding. The board rotates.

The board+athlete system have pushed the planet ever so slightly to the left and thus they have changed their velocity of travel to be larger in magnitude and more rightward in direction. The torque, paid for by the athlete against the resistance of friction, has aligned the board via clockwise rotation so that its wheels roll in the new direction of travel.

However, the athlete's own linear and angular momentum are independently conserved, so he is about spin around, fly off the board, and fall down. If he wishes to continue in the new direction of travel, he solves this problem by applying his weight roughly evenly to both axles and then doing a slower, less violent counter-torque. Because the axles are evenly loaded, the friction force on both sets of wheels is high enough to oppose the torque without sliding. If he wishes to resume his old direction of travel, he can abbreviate this process, and as soon as it's possible without losing balance, load the rear axle and do another push and torque in the opposite direction.

Neglecting rolling friction and wind resistance, iterating this two-step process will cause the athlete's speed to increase stepwise with the time-averaged velocity pointing in the direction of the slalom, as you have observed. In real life, rolling friction and drag will slow the athlete between pushes, so the athlete will soon reach a maximum of average velocity when his ability to do work on the ground per iteration equals the work done on him by drag and rolling friction per iteration.

Comment: Every skateboard I've seen has flexible bogeys, so the lateral force from the rider causes the direction of the wheels to change as well, rather than causing lateral sliding.